# Should I convert bootstrapped confidence intervals for logistic regression coefficients (betas) to CIs for odds ratios (ORs)?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, multiple-regression, bootstrap, odds-ratio

I have bootstrapped my multiple logistic regression model. SPSS does report OR and its confidence intervals for a **non**-bootstrapped multiple regression, but when it bootstraps the same model, it just gives B (beta) and CI for B.

I know OR is exponential of B and theoretically I can convert them to each other. But I don't know if I "should" do it in a **bootstrapped** model or not. I see SPSS refuses to compute OR alongside its CI for bootstrapped models; and instead, it gives only B and its CI for bootstrapped models.

Thus I thought perhaps it is not right to calculate confidence interval from "**bootstrapped**" beta CIs)

Am I right? Or can I compute ORs and their CIs by my own?

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't see a reason why you couldn't just take the exponential of the bootstrapped coefficient and CIs.

Comment: I just thought since bootstrapped confidence interval differs in method of calculation with normal confidence interval ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics) ), using it for OR CI calculation should be avoided. Don't know why SPSS does not report it, in the first place, while it does report OR and its CI for a normal regression (non-bootstrapped).

Comment: I don't know why SPSS doesn't report the ORs but that's not uncommon. In any case: you can just take the exponential of the bootstrapped coefficients and the CIs.

Comment: If the CI for B is legitimate, you should be able to just transform it to get a CI for a transformed B when the transform is monotonic. Bootstrapped CI's are generally just quantiles of the bootstrap distribution, there should be no issue transforming.