# The bootstrapped confidence intervals for ORs are strangely big or small in my binary logistic regression. Are they valid in the first place?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, bootstrap, odds-ratio, binary-data

This question is an extension to my previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60929/should-i-convert-bootstrapped-confidence-intervals-for-logistic-regression-coeff), although it is not repeated.

My bootstrapped ORs are OK. They are equal to non-bootstrapped ORs. However, the confidence intervals of the bootstrapped and non-bootstrapped regressions differ vastly.

While the non-bootstrapped regression reports for example OR's 95% CI ~= 1.2 to 2.3, the bootstrapped one reports OR's 95% CI ~= 1.1 to 25000.

It is **strange** and **non-practical**. My questions are:

1. Is this bootstrapped OR CI **correct**?
2. Can I keep my bootstrapped model in my study for its advantages, but report the non-bootstrapped OR CI?
3. Can I report both regressions?

Many thanks.

Comment: How many replications did you ask for?  In its simplest form the lower and upper bounds of the bootstrap confidence interval are the the 2.5$^{\mathrm{th}}$ and 97.5$^{\mathrm{th}}$ percentiles. So with only 200 replication the lower bound would the 5$^{\mathrm{th}}$ smallest and upper bound would be the 195$^{\mathrm{th}}$ largest value. So with only a few replications those bounds can become unstable. The solution would then be to just increase the number of replications. 20,000 is a number that often works well for me.

Comment: Many many many many many thanks. I would be so willing to upvote your nice answer, if you just add your comment as an "answer". My problem is my SPSS cannot run more than 3000 or 4000 replications. For example I set it to 10,000 times, and it worked for hours and hours, just to show finally an error message like "after this time stamp, the results were lost" or something like that (I don't recall precisely). So I have to use other software.

Comment: (I tried even with 5000 replications, but the same error happened again)

Comment: the error is: "any changes made to the working file  at this date/time  have been lost"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the bootstrap facilities of SPSS, but if you can save the bootstrap estimates and inspect those then that may give a hint of what is going on. Below is how I would start in Stata. In this case there is no problem. In your case I would suspect to see a bimodal distribution: a set of samples will be unproblematic and another set will suffer from some problem (e.g. near perfect separation) and will have odds ratios that are off the chart.

```
. sysuse nlsw88, clear
(NLSW, 1988 extract)

. tempfile bootstr

. logit union grade i.race i.south, ///
>    vce(bootstrap, reps(1000) saving(`bootstr') nodots)

Logistic regression                             Number of obs      =      1876
                                                Replications       =      1000
                                                Wald chi2(4)       =     87.46
                                                Prob > chi2        =    0.0000
Log likelihood =  -999.6188                     Pseudo R2          =    0.0434

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |   Observed   Bootstrap                         Normal-based
       union |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       grade |   .0926698   .0242889     3.82   0.000     .0450643    .1402752
             |
        race |
          2  |   .7702856   .1290322     5.97   0.000     .5173872    1.023184
          3  |    .369605   .4915077     0.75   0.452    -.5937324    1.332942
             |
     1.south |  -.9055953   .1204879    -7.52   0.000    -1.141747   -.6694433
       _cons |  -2.239574    .338928    -6.61   0.000    -2.903861   -1.575287
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. use `bootstr'
(bootstrap: logit)

. gen or_grade = exp(union_b_grade)

. hist or_grade
(bin=29, start=1.0278064, width=.00504198)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran a simulation where bootstrap nonparametric confidence limits for odds ratios had horrendous coverage, and the distribution of bootstrapped log odds ratios was not sensible.  Wald intervals were relatively OK. The "basic bootstrap" did far better than the percentile bootstrap.

Comment: i am testing it...

Comment: In SPSS there was no "basic bootstrapping". If you meant "Simple Bootstrap" by "Basic", I was already doing it. But if by "Basic" vs "Percentile" bootstraps, you meant "the types of CI", I changed the "Percentile" CI to "BCA" CI. The result was much stranger. Which program did you use? I assume R?

Comment: BCa intervals were no better.  This doesn't relate to how the bootstraps are done, but only to how they are put together to get confidence intervals.  In the R `boot` package `boot.ci` function this is `type="basic"`.  It is neither percentile nor BCa.  See http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/402/lectures/08-bootstrap/lecture-08.pdf

Comment: Many many many thanks. :) I should finally swithc to R, apparently!

Comment: Dear Frank, I found your package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/rms.pdf . I just can say "wow"! I hope I can use it although I am more lost! I am making a thread asking for syntax help.

Comment: Thanks.  See my short course notes at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/CourseBios330

Comment: (by the way, with the nice and superfast help of the community (COOLserdash), I fixed the code.